# JavaScript form submit in a form contains a submit button

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Here is the scenario:
I have 2 buttons, one in a form with the type and name `submit` and the other is a link which submits the form with an `onclick` event.

Since my form already has a submit button named submit, the JavaScript function `form.submit()` is not being sent. Because I'm using a framework I cannot change the name of submit button.

I have tried to add the style `display: none` to the submit button but that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
<form method="post" action="../../process_form.php">
submit button
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="button" id="label_forsubmit" name="submit">

link
<a class="standart_link" onclick="javascript: YAHOO.wsc.ExpensecontrolOperationsSubmit('a','0','b');" href="javascript:">cancel</a>
</form>
```

JavaScript part:

```
var btn = document.getElementById(btn_div);
var parentForm = YAHOO.util.Dom.getAncestorByTagName(btn_div, 'form' );
parentForm.submit.style.disabled = 'none';
parentForm.submit();
```

Comment: If you're using a framework that produces form buttons with the name "submit", then you're using a broken framework.  What framework is it?

Comment: It is a custom framework and sadly i am not permitted to change code over there :(

Comment: OK, well the problem is that that behavior is essentially a serious bug.

Comment: @Pointy is correct — this *is* a serious bug. If you're not permitted to make changes to the framework code, then you need to find somebody who is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend alerting the creators of the framework.  Something this serious should be fixed at the source of the problem, and adjusting the name of an element should be a small change for them.

In the meantime, you could remove the form element during the click event, storing it in a temporary variable.  Then, call `submit` and finally add the button back in during the `onsubmit` event.

Something like this, for example:

```
(function () { 
    var btn, sibling, 
        form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    window.linkSubmit = function () {
        if (form.submit.tagName) { // is submit actually an element?
            btn = form.submit;
            sibling = btn.nextSibling;
        }

        YAHOO.wsc.ExpensecontrolOperationsSubmit('a','0','b');
    }

    form.onsubmit = function () {
        if (btn) {
            this.insertBefore(btn, sibling);
            btn = sibling = void 0;  // Reset the variables
        }
    }
})();
```

And, changing your link markup to this:

```html
<a class="standart_link" onclick="linkSubmit()" href="javascript:">cancel</a>
```

As a side note, I'd recommend abstracting your JS code from your HTML markup entirely.

Comment: I'm so spoiled by the luxury of having control over virtually all the code I deal with that I've got no skills for clever workarounds like this :-)